# Check if a week of dates sits between two specific dates SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have two dates and want to only keep rows where a certain week falls in between those two dates. I need to run this for 67+ different weeks so I'd like to change my below code to run quicker and not have to type out the 7 days of the week each time.

```
SELECT * FROM MY_DATA
WHERE  ('05-JUNE-2017' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
OR      '06-JUNE-2017' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
OR      '07-JUNE-2017' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
OR      '08-JUNE-2017' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
OR      '09-JUNE-2017' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
OR      '10-JUNE-2017' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
OR      '11-JUNE-2017' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date);
```

Comment: Why did you write Oracle in the title but tagged SQL Server? Which one is it?

Comment: "I have two dates".  I see 7 date constants and two date columns.  I'm confused.

Comment: There are 2 date constants start_date and end_date. In my question i say "I need to run this for 67+ different weeks" so the dates i specify i.e 5/6/2017-11/6/2017 will need to change 67+ times. I don't want to have to do type the weekly dates out 67+ times. As said in the question.

Comment: @stickybit sorry SQL Oracle, that tag got added by mistake.

Comment: How do you "input" a week? In your current code you have hard-coded seven different (consecutive) dates. Are you simply giving ONE date, as the first day of a "week" (regardless of whether it is a Sunday, Monday or whatever)? And want to consider all seven days starting with (and including) the "given" date?

Comment: Also: don't EVER use strings as substitute for dates. Do write `TO_DATE('07-JUNE-2017', 'dd-MONTH-yyyy')` (including the format model!) - and best to use all numbers, like 07-06-2017, so that the code is not language-dependent (your colleagues in Brazil or Italy can run it without modifications).

Comment: i think it will be easier to understand what you need, if you add sample data and the expected result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you have two date intervals. One is from `input_date` to `input_date + 6` (note: 6, not 7; you are counting the `input_date` too!) and the other is from `start_date` to `end_date`. And you want to write a condition that means the two intervals overlap (have non-empty intersection).

Two intervals do **not** overlap if one entirely precedes the other. So, the last day of one interval must be strictly less than the first day of the other interval. This can happen in one of two ways (depending on *which* interval comes first). The condition would look like this:

```
input_date + 6 < start_date OR end_date < input_date
```

So, this is the negation of the condition you want. Apply the logical `NOT` operator to this; so the condition becomes:

```
input_date + 6 >= start_date AND end_date >= input_date
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM MY_DATA WHERE  ('05-JUNE-2017' BETWEEN start_date - 6 AND end_date );
```

where `'05-JUNE-2017'` is the initial day of the week you are looking for.

Now you have to do this for all the initial week days...

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: No because what if the start_date is '06-JUNE-2017'?

Comment: But when you say "certain week falls in between two dates", you mean completely or partially? So: if a week goes from 5th to 11th of one month and your start date is the 7th and the end_date is 15th, is this a valid week?

Comment: The existing code (which the OP says is correct, just too complicated) means that the OP is looking for "partially" (overlap), not "completely". "Completely" would require logical `AND`; the OP used `OR`.

Comment: If it's partially, then your answer is correct. I'll change mine accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like the following:

```
WITH weeks AS (SELECT TO_DATE('05-07-2017', 'DD-MM-RRRR') + LEVEL * 7 - 7 week_start
                    , TO_DATE('05-07-2017', 'DD-MM-RRRR') + LEVEL * 7 - 1 week_end
                 FROM dual
                 CONNECT BY LEVEL < 50)
SELECT * 
  FROM MY_DATA
  JOIN WEEKS
    ON MY_DATA.end_date   >= weeks.week_start
   AND MY_DATA.start_date <= weeks.week_end
```

The first part gets you some consecutive weeks then you join them with your data to get the desired results.

Comment: Why do you insist on `RRRR`? That makes no sense - it just shows ignorance. Any kind of `RR` or `RRRR` only existed around year 2000, to deal with the Y2K problem (years stored as two digits). For four-digit years `RRRR` and `YYYY` are the same, and there's no reason to use `RRRR`.

Comment: As you said - it makes no difference, so why do you insist on changing a correct answer??? It has nothing todo with ignorance there is just no point in changing it...

Comment: I do not "insist" on changing it; I changed it once, trying to help, you changed it back, I left it alone. I just don't understand it. You still didn't explain why you use `RRRR` where most people would use `YYYY`. Again, `RRRR` only exists to deal with a legacy issue. We are 19 years past that, so why are you still using `RRRR`?

Comment: When working with oracle forms for example it is beneficial to use `RRRR` as then the user can enter the date with 2- or 4- digits which would otherwise need much programming. So the general use of `RRRR` instead of `YYYY` makes sense regardless of the Y2K problem, as it's still beneficial in some cases and makes no difference in the others...